# XML validation using complex type extension

Tags: xml, xsd

My problem is quite simple, i have a first XSD schema that define types with the following structure :

```
<complexType name="A">
    <!-- attribute / element definition here -->
</complexType>
```

This first schema belongs to the namespace **a**. Then i have a second schema that also define another type that imports the first one :

```
<complexType name="B">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="a:A">
            <!-- attribute / element definition here -->
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

This time the second schema belongs to **b** namespace. Everything works until here : i have a third schema that defines a document structure like this :

```
<element name="root">
    <sequence>
         <element name="A" type="a:A"></element>
    </sequence>
</element>
```

When i write an XML file that respects this schema it works perfectly, but i would like to be able to substitute the a:A element by a b:B element, namely :

```
<root xmlns="mythirdschema" xmlns:a="firstschema" xmlns:b="secondschema">
    <b:B>
        <!-- Attribute / element imposed by a:A definition -->
        <!-- Attribute / element imposed by b:B extension -->
    </b:B>
</root>
```

But it does not work, when i attempt to validate my XML file using third schema, it tolds me that an **a:A** element is expected, not a **b:B**.

Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing elements and types. The definition of the `root` element requires it to have a child element named `A` (either in no namespace or in the thirdschema namespace, depending on the third schema's `elementFormDefault`), but the *type* of that element can be a subtype such as `b:B`.  So it would validate

```
<root xmlns="mythirdschema" xmlns:a="firstschema" xmlns:b="secondschema">
    <A>
        <!-- Attribute / element imposed by a:A definition -->
    </A>
</root>
```

(using the base `a:A` type for the `{mythirdschema}A` element), or

```
<root xmlns="mythirdschema" xmlns:a="firstschema" xmlns:b="secondschema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <A xsi:type="b:B">
        <!-- Attribute / element imposed by a:A definition -->
        <!-- Attribute / element imposed by b:B extension -->
    </A>
</root>
```

(using the `b:B` subtype).

If you wanted to change the element name rather than using `xsi:type` then you'd have to have global *element* declarations as well as type declarations in the various schemas and use a substitution group:

**first schema**

```
<complexType name="A">
  <!-- attribute / element definition here -->
</complexType>

<element name="A" type="a:A" /><!-- assuming xmlns:a="firstschema" -->
```

**second schema**

```
<complexType name="B">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="a:A">
            <!-- attribute / element definition here -->
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>

<!-- assuming appropriate xmlns:a and xmlns:b -->
<element name="B" type="b:B" substitutionGroup="a:A" />
```

**third schema**

```
<element name="root">
    <sequence>
         <element ref="a:A"/>
    </sequence>
</element>
```

This would then validate either

```
<root xmlns="mythirdschema" xmlns:a="firstschema">
    <a:A>
        <!-- Attribute / element imposed by a:A definition -->
    </a:A>
</root>
```

(notice here the A element is in the first rather than third schema namespace), or

```
<root xmlns="mythirdschema" xmlns:b="secondschema">
    <b:B>
        <!-- Attribute / element imposed by a:A definition -->
        <!-- Attribute / element imposed by b:B extension -->
    </b:B>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, i just lost a day to find out the xsi:type declaration you gave me.

Comment: @Faylixe I've added a bit more explanation of the substitution group approach.

Comment: I have seen that, but i think the type approach fits better to my problem :). Anyways having the substitution group is always interesting.